# JSP file not running

Tags: java, spring, jsp, encoding, runtime-error

I'm trying to write simple exercise from tutorial. And this part of JSP code gives me an error.

```
 <c:url var="addAction" value="songs/add"/>
     <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="song">  
         <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="AddSong"/>"/>
```

redirects me on page

> http://localhost:8080/$%7BaddAction%7D

and write

> description The requested resource is not available.

What is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path, for example:

If you wrote: `<c:url var="addAction" value="songs/add"/>`

Try to use: `<c:url var="addAction" value="http://localhost:8080/songs/add"/>`

Or second option is to use Spring URL tag library, you can take a look here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.url

and for example:

```
<spring:url value="/something" var="url" htmlEscape="true"/>
<a href="${url}">...</a>
```